# WalkDir crate stuck reporting "invalid input" with error code 22

Tags: linux, rust

I am attempting to write a quick app to inventory specific files throughout the file system on my Linux OS. My expectation is that I will have to deal with permission issues, etc. What is unexpected is that the directory walk appears to get stuck reporting invalid input errors (os error 22). My code is as follows:

```
extern crate walkdir;

use walkdir::WalkDir;
use std::env;
use std::io;
use std::path::Path;

fn main() {
    let args: Vec<String> = env::args().collect();
    println!("{:?}", args);
    for entry in WalkDir::new(&args[1]) {
        match entry {
            Ok(_) => {}, // println!("{:?}", res.path().display()),
            Err(err) => {
                let path = err.path().unwrap_or(Path::new("")).display();
                println!("failed to access entry '{}'", path);
                if let Some(inner) = err.io_error() {
                    match inner.kind() {
                        // The operation lacked the necessary privileges to complete.
                        io::ErrorKind::PermissionDenied => {
                            // println!("  --> permission denied: {}", inner);
                        },
                        // A parameter was incorrect.
                        io::ErrorKind::InvalidInput => {
                            // If you println! instead, the app misbehaves
                            panic!("  --> invalid input: {}", inner);
                        },
                        // Any I/O error not part of this list.
                        io::ErrorKind::Other => {
                            println!("  --> other: {}", inner);
                        },

                        _ => {} // While debugging the issue, silence all other errors
                    }
                }
            }
        }
    }
}
```

Since there is no path associated with the error, it is difficult to diagnose where the error arises. If the library is in a loop and no longer walking the tree, then this would be a bug. If there are additional guards necessary to eliminate directories into which the app cannot descend, how does one ensure that those directories are not processed.

I know that there is an option to iterate with a filter to eliminate the issue, but since this is for an audit application, the additional visibility is important. The examples of filter functions are simply masking all issues without reporting them.

Comment: Have you tried running your program through `strace`? If this error comes from the OS, then you should be able to see it in `strace`'s output, along with the parameters that were passed to the problematic call.

Comment: Thanks for the tip. The segment right before it crashes looks like this (my apologies for the run-on text). Seems to be stuck in a proc task. open("/proc/4234/task/4234/net", O_RDONLY|O_NONBLOCK|O_DIRECTORY|O_CLOEXEC) = 8
fstat(8, {st_mode=S_IFDIR|0555, st_size=0, ...}) = 0
getdents(8, 0x7f69754d4a70, 32768)      = -1 EINVAL (Invalid argument)
write(1, "failed to access entry ''\n", 26) = 26

Comment: `/proc` and `/sys` are full of virtual files that often act strangely. If you're only interested in physical files, you should exclude them. If you want to be rigorous, you would exclude mount points of type `proc` and `sysfs`, and perhaps some more. Also, I can't reproduce your problem on my Linux system when I run `cargo run /`.